# gnuplot 2D polar plot with heatmap from 3D dataset - possible?

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap

I'd like to take a plot that I have done as a surface in 3D using cartesian coordinates and view it as a heatmap in 2D in POLAR coordinates. The reason for this is I am obtaining data on a system in that coordinate system. I've only found some related examples, but am getting stuck trying to get it to work with my data. I am currently using the matrix format, and I can reformat the data set if this would help get the chart working.

The data is SPL measurements taken on a loudspeaker. The microphone is positioned at a fixed distance away (e.g. fixed radius) and measurements are made at every 10 degrees around the entire loudspeaker horizontally. The SPL measurement is obtained as a function of frequency, 20Hz to 20kHz.

I would like to use gnuplot to create a 2D polar plot. Frequency would be plotted as the radius, the angle around the loudspeaker would be the angle, and the "height" would be the SPL level. This should generate a surface, however, I would like to create a heat map pm3d and then view that from above (e.g. view 0,0) or as a 2D plot. I also need to add contour lines that show intervals of SPL and superimpose that on the heat map.

I found something similar for cartesian coordinates here:
http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.com/2009/07/maps-contour-plots-with-labels.html
When I tried this approach using polar coordinates for the final 2D plot, I got an error message that the "with image" option is not supported for polar plots. Can someone try this or confirm this?

I have been able to plot my polar data as a heatmap+contour lines in 3D using splot and view from directly above (set view 0.0). If I first convert my existing polar coordinate data into cartesian coordinates I will probably get something like what is shown in this web page:
[how to create a 3d polar graph with gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156095/how-to-create-a-3d-polar-graph-with-gnuplot)
I could view this from above, too, but I would like to add in the polar grid and have labels for the angle and radius. Would I have to do this manually or could I use multiplot to overlay a 2D grid and the 3D plot viewed from 0.0?

I am not sure how to approach this. Any advice about what direction to take would be appreciated.

-Charlie

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `image` plotting works only for equally distributed rectangular grids, just like any bitmap image is arranged. Otherwise you must use `splot` with `pm3d`.

The `set grid polar` works only for 2D, so you must use `multiplot` to overlay your heatmap with the polar grid. Here a, quite lengthy, example to show you how it might work:

```
reset
set terminal pngcairo size 800,800
set output '3d-polar.png'

set lmargin at screen 0.05
set rmargin at screen 0.85
set bmargin at screen 0.1
set tmargin at screen 0.9

set pm3d map
unset key

set multiplot

# plot the heatmap
set parametric
set isosamples 500

unset border
unset xtics
unset ytics

set angles degree
r = 6
set urange[0:r] # radius
set vrange[0:360] # angle
set xrange[-r:r]
set yrange[-r:r]
set colorbox user origin 0.9,0.1 size 0.03,0.8
splot u*cos(v), u*sin(v), (cos(v)*besj0(2*u))**2

# now plot the polar grid only
set style line 11 lc rgb 'white' lw 2
set grid polar ls 11
set polar
set rrange[0:r]
unset raxis
set rtics format '' scale 0
unset parametric
set for [i=0:330:30] label at first (r+0.35)*cos(i), first (r+0.35)*sin(i)\
center sprintf('%d', i)
plot NaN w l
unset multiplot
```

The result is:

[image]

And now some details about some tricks:

- In order to get a square size, you can't use `set size ratio 1`, because the margins differ for the 2D and 3D plots, even if you would specify some absolute margins. Therefore, I set a square canvas size (terminal option `size 800,800`), and set appropriate absolute margins.
- You cannot `unset rtics` because then the grid would disappear.
- The grid labels must be set manually.
- The colorbox was also set manually because otherwise it would have overlapped with the `0` label.
- Plotting `NaN` does only plot the grid

Comment: I was able to get everything working on my build (Win32: Version 4.7 patchlevel 0) EXCEPT: the line with sprintf generates an error that says "undefined variable: at". Also, I need to supply a data file and I am somewhat confused about the file format. Should this be x,y,z data points (continuous data)? Can I use matrix format?

Comment: More specifically, how can I take my input data file (frequency, angle, SPL) and use the parametric mode u and v to cast this in a polar form. I think that is why Christoph did using a functional form for the data. But I need to use points from a file, and I would like to understand how this should work. Thanks!

Comment: Thinking about the input data a little more, it seems like the parametric mode commands have nothing to do with that... they were just useful for constructing the polar data set. I think that I will have to convert my data, which is already in polar form (r, theta, z) into Cartesian form using x=r*cos(theta), y=r*sin(theta), z. Then I will be able to use it directly in the splot command. I tried something like 'splot 'matrix.dat' nonuniform matrix using 1*cos(2):1*sin(2):3' and 'splot 'matrix.dat' nonuniform matrix using $1*cos($2):$1*sin($2):$3' but these did not work for me.

Comment: Wow this answer really helped me with my problem. After photoshop was not precise, and HTML CSS was not excact, gnuplot came to the reascue:                                  `set pm3d map
unset key

# plot the heatmap
set parametric
set isosamples 5000

unset border
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset colorbox

set angles degree
r = 6
set urange[0:r] # radius
set vrange[0:360] # angle
set xrange[-r:r]
set yrange[-r:r]
set size ratio 1
set palette gray
set terminal gif size 3000,3000
set output 'output9.gif'

splot u*cos(v), u*sin(v), sin(v*21)

`

Answer (score 4):

I took the command file that Christoph posted and played around a bit and managed to get it working for my needs EXCEPT for the labels, which I am still having problems with. The plot is looking like this:

[image: limited angle polar plot with contours and pm3d surface]

In order to get this result, I had to recalculate the coordinates of my measurement data, changing them from a polar coordinate system (frequency=r, theta=off-axis angle, z=SPL) to a Cartesian one (x,y,z). At the same time I modified the way that the polar grid was presented. Although I wanted a logarithmic polar r-axis, Cartesian coordinates must be used for the pm3d data, so I took the log of the r data before using it to calculate x,y,z coordinates. Also, I knew that the minimum value of the polar log r-axis scale would be 10, and this seems to be set equal to the center of the plot when a logscale polar grid is used. In order for the grid and the surface data to line up properly, I subtracted log10(10) from the r values before using them to calculate the Cartesian coordinates used for the pm3d map. So in total, the equations I used were

```
r = log10( frequency ) - 1
x = r cos( theta )
y = r sin( theta )
z = SPL
```

I then used the following command file to plot the data:

```
reset 
set terminal pngcairo size 800,800 
set output '3d-polar.png'
set lmargin at screen 0.05
set rmargin at screen 0.85
set bmargin at screen 0.1
set tmargin at screen 0.9
set pm3d map interpolate 20,20
unset key
set multiplot

# plot the heatmap

set cntrparam levels increment 3,-3, -24
set contour surface
set palette rgb 33,13,10 #rainbow (blue-green-yellow-red)
set cbrange [-18:0]
unset border
unset xtics
unset ytics
set angles degree
r = 3.31
set xrange[-r:r]
set yrange[-r:r]
set colorbox user origin 0.9,0.1 size 0.03,0.8
splot 'new_test.dat' using 1:2:3

# now plot the polar grid only
set style line 11 lc rgb 'black' lw 1 lt 0
set grid polar ls 11
set polar
set logscale r 10
set rrange[10:20000]
unset raxis
set rtics format '' scale 0
set rtics (10,20,100,200,1000,2000,10000,20000)
#unset parametric
#set for [i=0:330:30] label at first (r+0.35)*cos(i), first (r+0.35)*sin(i) \
#center sprintf('%d', i)

plot NaN w l

unset multiplot
unset output
```

The data used to generate the plot only span +/- 30 degrees, so only that sector fills the polar plot. Additional angular data can be used to fill out the plot.

If I can get some help with labels, I can call this "done". I still need to get the labels of angle working. Input on how to label the polar r-axis tics that would be very welcome, too.

Comment: I also tested my script with both 4.6.3 and current 4.7 and the labeling works fine. Instead of using `set for ...` you can also try with a `do for [i=0:330:30]{ set label ... }`. Likewise you could also label the `r` values above the heatmap.

Comment: I figured out the source of the error: The `set label` command syntax seems to require an identifier tag to follow `label` in the sequence of specifiers. The tag must be a positive integer. I based this on i, e.g. `set for [i=0:330:30] label i/30+1 at...`. I think that the reason I was getting the error previously was that gnuplot was trying to interpret `at` as the tag. There is more info on this here: http://www.manpagez.com/info/gnuplot/gnuplot-4.4.3/gnuplot_259.php                 .

Comment: No, the `<tag>`is not required, as explicitely stated in the page you refer to: `If no <tag> is given, the lowest unused tag value is assigned automatically.`. But I don't understand, why you get an error with 4.7 (which date?).

Comment: I'm using the MinGW build of version 4.7 patchlevel 0 last modified 2012-09-16. I came across this problem once before, where I had to explicitly specify a tag or I got an error, so maybe this is a bug.

Comment: Yes, that would be a bug, but you are using a one year old version of the development branch, you should consider updating it `:)`. With the version dated 2013-09-09 it definitely works. Try the latest precompiled binary dated 2013-08-01 http://www.gnuplot.info/development/binaries/.

Comment: I didn't realize that I was so far behind the times... :) Thanks! I downloaded the 1-AUG-2013 binary, edited out the tag from the line, and everything works perfectly. Thanks again for all your help @Christoph !!!

Comment: It is only far behind for a development version, because it can always happen, that such a bug is introduced when making some other changes. Maybe it was already fixed a few days later.

Comment: I am having some problems with the contour line styles. This seemed to be important enough to create a new question on the topic, which you can find here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878163/gnuplot-contour-line-color-set-style-line-and-set-linetype-not-working