# Gnuplot contour plot without dots

Tags: gnuplot, contour

I am trying to plot a contour plot with labels with the following code.

```
reset
set terminal qt
set pm3d map
set contour base
set cntrparam levels incremental 0, 10, 100
set cntrlabel onecolor
set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10

# No key appears
# splot 'temperature.dat' with pm3d title "Heated 2D plate"

# Key appears
splot 'temperature.dat' with pm3d, \
   'temperature.dat' with labels title "Heated 2D plate"
```

The outputs are shown below:

No labels (first splot command) and without key
[image: Heated 2D plate without labels]

With labels and key (2nd splot command), but with dots.
[image: Heated 2D plate with labels]

My questions:

1. Why is the key not appearing in the first splot command?
2. How to remove the dots when plotting with labels (2nd splot command)?

Will attach the data file if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. key

The key for the "with pm3d" plot is probably covered by the pm3d surface. You can move it to the front and make it distinct from the surface coloring using `set key box opaque`.  This will label the contours in the key as well as on the plot. To remove the redundant contour labels in the key

```
  set pm3d explicit
  set key box opaque
  splot 'temperature.dat' with pm3d notitle,\
        'temperature.dat' with labels title "Heated 2D plate"
```

2. dots

I am not sure why the dots appear. I do not see them when I try to reproduce the plot. Try `set pm3d noborder`

Comment: I was hoping that I would get the answer for the "dots" problem too from some other user. Baring that, the key problem is answered with the above answer from @Ethan.

Comment: I have a guess at a possible bug that would cause dots.  If my guess is correct, you could avoid it by using "set hidden3d".

Comment: Thanks. The `set hidden3d` command removed the dots. However, the contour lines have changed from black to white now. Any idea how to change them to white? Using `splot 'temperature.dat' with pm3d linecolor -1` didn't help.

Comment: Okay, so I found this SO link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878163/gnuplot-contour-line-color-set-style-line-and-set-linetype-not-working which talks about this. Also found the bug report https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1284/. However, still not sure how to fix the linecolor of the contours.

Comment: Found out the following works: `splot 'temperature.dat' with pm3d linestyle -1` This would change the linecolor to black. Note that the term `linecolor` doesn't work. But `linestyle` works just fine.