# gnuplot pm3d with contour base

Tags: 3d, gnuplot

I would like to add the contour lines in the plane z=0 of this plot : [image]

in order to obtain something similar to this other (recovered from a book)
[image]

how cam I do it with gnuplot ? consider that the code to generate the pm3d plot is the follow:

```
set terminal pdfcairo enhanced font "palatino,42" fontscale 1.0 size 30, 22 background rgb 'white'
 set output 'stromegaJPDF_90.pdf'
#set border 4095 front lt black linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid
set style line 100  linecolor rgb "#f0e442"  linewidth 0.500 dashtype solid pointtype pointsize default
 #set view 50, 220, 1, 1
set samples 30, 30
set isosamples 30, 30
set surface
set title "Re=90"
 set cbrange [ * : * ] noreverse writeback
 set rrange [ * : * ] noreverse writeback
 set pm3d implicit at s
 set pm3d depthorder
 set pm3d interpolate 1,1 flush begin noftriangles border linecolor rgb "gray"  linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid corners2color mean
 set xrange[0:15]
  set logscale z
  set xlabel '{/Symbol w}^2/<{/Symbol w}^2>' enhanced
  set ylabel 'cos({/Symbol w}, W)' enhanced
   splot 'jpdfstrW_90.dat' t 'JPDF'
```

jpdfsrtW_90.dat is reported here [enter link description here](https://pastebin.com/qkuF1KKM)

Comment: On a logarithmic scale, you cannot reach 0. Can you please share `jpdfstrW_90.dat`?

Comment: sure ! find enclosed in the main question

Comment: I would like to obtain the projection ... like in the second graph reported !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have the data in a grid structure, i.e. equal number of entries in each block (e.g. 100 in your case), butin your first and last block, you have fewer entries than general. [After fixing it](https://github.com/danieltuzes/collection/blob/6ddf0ad4e1763e76dc40c1148e0d2950faca8ef1/SO/gnuplot_pm3d_contour/jpdfstrW_90.dat), it should work by adding `set contour both`. On a log scale, you cannot expect the `z=0` to be shown, and you also need to fix the problem of exactly `z=0` values to have a decent view.

For a simplified plot file, consider the following example:

```
set contour both
set pm3d border linewidth 0.2

set logscale z
set zrange [1e-5:]

splot 'jpdfstrW_90.dat' u 1:2:($3+1e-5) w pm3d t 'JPDF'
```

To make the contour thicker, replot the data with contour only:

```
splot 'jpdfstrW_90.dat' u 1:2:($3+1e-5) w pm3d t 'JPDF', "" u 1:2:($3+1e-5) t 'JPDF' with lines nosurf lw 2
```

This latter produces:
[image]

To further [customize contour lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878163/gnuplot-contour-line-color-set-style-line-and-set-linetype-not-working), you need to define the lines manually. To customize the counter levels, check out [cntrparam](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node166.html). If log z is used, maybe it is more natural to use a logarithmic color bar too. You could also try [different color palettes](http://www.kennethmoreland.com/color-advice/) that are based on scientific principles.

Consider the following script for customized contour lines:

```
set contour both
set pm3d border linewidth 0.2

set linetype 1 lc rgb "black" lw 1.5 dt 1
set linetype 2 lc rgb "black" dt 1
set linetype 3 lc rgb "black" dashtype 2
set linetype 4 lc rgb "black" dashtype 3
set linetype 5 lc rgb "black" dashtype 4
set style line 1 lc rgb 'black' lw 1.5 dt 1
set style line 2 lc rgb 'black' dt 1
set style line 3 lc rgb 'black' dashtype 2
set style line 4 lc rgb 'black' dashtype 3
set style line 5 lc rgb 'black' dashtype 4

set logscale z
set zrange [1e-5:]
set log cb
set cntrparam levels discrete 1, 0.1, 0.002, 0.0005
splot 'jpdfstrW_90.dat' u 1:2:($3+1e-5) w pm3d notitle, "" u 1:2:($3+1e-5) t 'JPDF' with lines nosurf
```

[image]

Comment: and how to do the line to the same colour but different styles? and how to choose the frequency instead of 1 , 0.1, 0.001

Comment: nice !! there is a way to obtain the contours lines of the same colour and different styles?  and it is as well possible to choose the frequency (different respect z=1 z=0.1 z=0.01 ...)