# Gnuplot: set angular grid limits in polar plot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to make a wedge-shaped plot in polar coordinates spanning from 0 to 60 degrees. Something like the following figure: Wedge-plot I want

[image]

However, the command "trange" is used for the range of the plot, not of the grid itself, and I always end up with the full-circle grid, like this: Same plot but with full grid.

[image]

Is there a simple command to set the limits in the angle variable? Here is the code I used to plot the former figure in gnuplot 5.2

```
set terminal pngcairo enhanced font "arial,10" fontscale 1.0 size 600, 400 
set output 'polar1.png'

unset key
set border 4096 lt black linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid
unset xtics
unset ytics
set size ratio 1 1,1

set raxis
set ttics 0.00000,30 font ":Italic"

set polar
set grid polar 30.0000 lw 1.5
plot cos(4*t) lt 3 lw 2
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This reminds me to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72723326/7295599  Does the answer there maybe help?

Comment: It does, but it's not ideal. Is there a simpler command? I know in matplotlib you can just write "set_thetamax(60)". Can I write my own external function with the code from that answer to call it every time I desire? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is no "intended" way to limit the maximum angle in a polar plot.
So, there is a simpler (but ugly) workaround, which simply covers the unwanted part by a filled polygon.

**Note:** There will be an issue if your `rmax` is not an integer multiple of `rtic 0.2`, i.e. a plot with `rmax=1.05` will not look as desired. Therefore, as a workaround an extra rtic at `rmax` is added.

**Script:**

```
### plot only part of polar plot
reset session

rmax = 1.05
amax = 60

set polar
set rrange [0:rmax]
set rtics 0.2 scale 0.5
set rtics add ('' rmax)
set grid r polar 10 lt black lw .3

set trange [0:2*pi]
set ttics 0,10 format "%g°" font ":Italic" scale 0.5,0.25 offset -1,0
set mttics 2

set xlabel "r-label"
set xrange [0:rmax]
unset xtics
set yrange [0:rmax]
unset ytics

set size square
set border 4096
set lmargin 0
set tmargin 0
unset title
unset key
set samples 300

set obj 1 polygon from graph 0,0 to first rmax*cos(pi/180*amax),rmax*sin(pi/180*amax) \
            to first rmax*cos(pi/180*amax), screen 1.0 \
            to first 0, screen 1 to screen 0,1 to screen 0,0 to graph 0,0 \
                  fc rgb 0xffffff fs solid 1.0 front
set arrow 1 from graph 0,0 to first rmax*cos(pi/180*amax),rmax*sin(pi/180*amax) lc "black" nohead front

plot cos(4*t) lt 3 lw 2
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I am looking for and your workaround code is simple enough to be understood and changed as desired